# how print very high resolution image (deleting white background) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, print-composer

I would like to print something like this .TIFF image :

[image]

but I need to do it with a high resolution,so I have been told to use QGIS and especially the print composer to create an object that can be set with a certain resolution starting from 300dpi to be printed.

My problem is that when I load my tiff as a raster,first I see this image in QGIS like that :

[image]

and that could seems ok, but the in the print composer the added object is my image with the whole white background :

[image]

and that background is also included in the object when I try so save it as an image with a specific resolution. 
So how can I put away this white background immediately in QGIS ,without bringing it also in the print composer? 
please help me!!

Comment: Did you try to adjust the map scale settings in Composer?

Comment: actually not, because it is the first time I use this, and I do not know how to modify those settings. :(

Comment: If you click the item (you already have according to the screenshot) and just look in the right panel - there is a card/subpanel called Item properties (Proprieta ... on your screenshot) and there you find scale settings.

Comment: I have tried to adjust the scale ( it is a really good hint) but the position of the image is really in the lower part of the background and it is not possible to move it from that position. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Yes, there is a tool to move your map "inside" of the frame - use the tool under the one you use to select the items and you can move the content inside.

Comment: yes,I managed to find the right way to customize everything and get my image!!! So I have to thank you so much for your hints. Do you know which is the best resolution (dpi ) for printing?

Comment: I am mostly using 300 dpi PNG but sometimes it is terribly big so I use JPG.